# FCM Push notification didn't receive when app is in foreground but receive when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Push notification not receive when App is in foreground but receive while App in background i have followed FCM tutorial from https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/gcm-setup-for-android-push-notifications-656cfdd8adbd

Comment: Which device you are trying?

Comment: Android 6.0 device

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way and implementing [this plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/PushNotification).

And when device ready I fired this code:

```
 pushNotification.register(
function (result) {
    //Do some stuff
}, function (error) {
    //Do some stuff on error 
}, {
    "badge":"true",
    "sound":"true",
    "alert":"true",
    "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
});
```

And also implemented below function:

```
function onNotificationAPN(event) {
  if (event) {
    if ( event.alert ) {
      alert(Recieved alert: + event.alert);
    }
    if ( event.sound ) {
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
    }
    if ( event.badge ) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
        //SetApplicationIconBadgeNumber success.
      }, function() {
        //SetApplicationIconBadgeNumber error.
      },
      event.badge);
    }
  }
}
```